# Android Studio app won't run on my phone anymore but it does on other devices

Tags: android-studio

After a random run, without changing anything, the app I'm developing is no longer running on my phone.
I gave it some thought and finally decided to test it on another device only to find out that it works perfectly. Emulators work as well. This is a big bottleneck in my development since I can only use emulators as of now.

This is the error that I'm getting:

`Error while executing: am start -n "com.university.hobi_android/com.university.hobi_android.ui.main.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.university.hobi_android/.ui.main.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.university.hobi_android/com.university.hobi_android.ui.main.MainActivity} does not exist.`

Android Studio 3.5.1.

Device is running Android Pie

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.university.hobi_android">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try "Rebuild" or "Invalidate Caches and Restart" - especially if you mess with the app ID Android Studio sometimes gets confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. What I had to do was to go into the `build.gradle` file of my module and change the `applicationId`, `versionCode` and `versionName` properties. It still doesn't run from android studio for some reason but it installing the app and running it off my phone works now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the below steps.

1. Start Android Studio
2. Switch the file view from "Android" to "Project" view
3. Delete .idea
4. Delete .gradle
5. Delete all *.iml files
6. Files -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart"
7. "Invalidate and Restart"

> **Note:-** Also, Disconnect the physical device and reconnect the device.

Comment: it did something very strange. the app reappeared on my phone and it did run when starting it from the phone but once I ran it again from android studio it went back to being the same thing